# Use a system wide Mutex

Tags: c#, winforms, mutex

I have a question when it comes to create a "System Wide Mutex" that will work with many instances of the same application.

So I want a process to be threadsafe as seen in the code where I write to the same file:
**Write to the same file**

I wonder if I do set this up programatically correct. For example I release the mutex when I close the form. I also set the bool to true (InitiallyOwned) for the mutex when I do create it?

I have tried to google this but are not sure I get a clean answer to it.
The use case would be to be able to open and close instances at random and always have the mutex in place.

```
public Form1()
{
    try
    {
        _mutex = System.Threading.Mutex.OpenExisting("systemWideMutex");
        _mutex.WaitOne(); //obtain a lock by waitone
        _mutex.ReleaseMutex(); //release
    }
    catch { _mutex = new System.Threading.Mutex(true, "systemWideMutex"); } //Create mutex for the first time

    new Thread(threadSafeWorkBetween2Instances).Start(); //Start process
}
void threadSafeWorkBetween2Instances()
{
    while (true)
    {
        try
        {
            _mutex = System.Threading.Mutex.OpenExisting("systemWideMutex");
            _mutex.WaitOne(); //obtain a lock by waitone

            //DO THREADSAFE WORK HERE!!!
            //Write to the same file

            _mutex.ReleaseMutex(); //release
        }
        catch { _mutex = new System.Threading.Mutex(true, "systemWideMutex"); } //Create mutex for the first time
        Thread.Sleep(10000);
    }
}
private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    _mutex.ReleaseMutex(); //release
}
```

Comment: The call to WaitOne on your mutex  is blocking in your case (because you're not providing a time out) so there's no point having a While loop trying to obtain a lock. And why are you creating a mutex in your exception handler ??

Comment: I see, will WaitOne() wait forever? and WaitOne(5000) wait for 5 seconds? I create it in the exception handler in case it have not been created yet by any other instance. I saw that in an example. Is that correct to use such approach?

Comment: It is far too buggy, you'll have to throw it away.  All you need is to *create* the mutex in the thread, the OS allows creating the mutex if it already exists and makes it atomic.  The ReleaseMutex call and Dispose() call belongs in a finally block.  If it must be system wide then the name needs to be prefixed with `"Global\"`.  That's all.

Comment: @Hans Passant If the mutex already exist, why/how can it again be created? Should I use Dispose() instead of ReleaseMutex() I am not sure of the difference in this case? Then, Global such In: "GlobalMutex" ?

Comment: @Andreas i suggest you have a thorough read of https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.mutex?view=netframework-4.7.2#examples. AND NO: IT'S BONKERS TO CREATE OBJECTS IN EXCEPTION HANDLERS !!

Comment: @auburg Thanks for the link. I have red that link before also. As this is a systemwide mutex and Not a normal mutex for one instance. I am not sure how to any other way to create it in a exception handler and release the mutex doesn't happen in a finally block on all examples I have seen. I will attempt an answer and see if I am closer to a solution. I am not sure if i need a timeout in the WaitHandle either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
     System.Threading.Mutex _mutex = null;
bool mutexWasCreated = false;
                public Form1()
                {
                    new Thread(threadSafeWorkBetween2Instances).Start();
                }
                void threadSafeWorkBetween2Instances()
                {
                     if(!_mutex.TryOpenExisting("GlobalsystemWideMutex"))
                     {
                        // Create a Mutex object that represents the system
                       // mutex named with
                       // initial ownership for this thread, and with the
                       // specified security access. The Boolean value that 
                       // indicates creation of the underlying system object
                       // is placed in mutexWasCreated.
                         //
                        _mutex = new Mutex(true, "GlobalsystemWideMutex", out 
                         mutexWasCreated, mSec);

                        if(!mutexWasCreated )
                        {
                              //report error
                         }
                     } 
                    while (true)
                    {
                        try
                        {                       
                            bool acquired = _mutex.WaitOne(5000); //obtain a lock - timeout after n number of seconds
                            if(acquired)
                            {   
                               try 
                               {
                                  //DO THREADSAFE WORK HERE!!!
                                  //Write to the same file
                               }
                               catch (Exception e)
                               {

                               }  
                               finally 
                               {
                                  _mutex.ReleaseMutex(); //release
                                  break;
                               }                          
                            }
                            else
                            {
                               Thread.Sleep(1000); // wait for n number of seconds before retrying
                            } 
                        }
                        catch {  } //Create mutex for the first time

                    }
                }
                private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
                {
                    try { _mutex.ReleaseMutex(); } catch { } //release
                }
```

Comment: I will put the releasemutex like you did there in the finally block. However, it seems to not be possible to: "OpenExisting("GlobalsystemWideMutex");" like that because it doesn't exist the first time and receives an exception: "No handle of the given name exists". This is why I put it in the exception handler?

Comment: I've edited my answer to take into the case where the mutex doesn't exist - see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.mutex.openexisting?view=netframework-4.7.2 for a more detailed example

Comment: Also i strongly recommend you store the global mutex name in a config file or at the least have it as a private member variable

Comment: Thank you, "TryOpenExisting" that was interesting. It seems to exist in Net 4.5. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Glad that helped